# Stopping a repeating Println in a while loop, BlueJ

Tags: java, bluej

Below is the code I have so far, it is a calculator for my computer science class. The problem I am having is that on the second run of the program the System.out.print("Would you like to perform a calculation? (y/n) "); runs twice instead of once. I have already turned in the project, but I would like to know why it does this and how, in my future programs, I can fix it. I'll post the rest of the code below.

I appreciate all of your help, I credit the "A" that I got on it to all of you. Thanks!

```
/**
* A calculator with multiple functions.
* @author () 
* @version (version 2.1)
*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calc
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cont = "", funct = "";
    double fnum = 0, snum = 0, answer = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.print("Would you like to perform a calculation? (y/n) ");
        cont = reader.nextLine();
        if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println("What function would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("+?");
            System.out.println("-?");
            System.out.println("*?");
            System.out.println("/?");
            funct = reader.nextLine();
            if (funct.equals("+"))
            {
                System.out.println("Simple addition calculator");
                System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
                fnum = reader.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
                snum = reader.nextDouble();
                answer = fnum + snum;
                System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            if (funct.equals("-"))
            {
                 System.out.println("Simple subtraction calculator");
                System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
                fnum = reader.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
                snum = reader.nextDouble();
                answer = fnum - snum;
                System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            if (funct.equals("*"))
            {
                 System.out.println("Simple multiplication calculator");
                System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
                fnum = reader.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
                snum = reader.nextDouble();
                answer = fnum * snum;
                System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            if (funct.equals("/"))
            {
                 System.out.println("Simple division calculator");
                System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
                fnum = reader.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
                snum = reader.nextDouble();
                answer = fnum / snum;
                System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
        else if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
        {
            break;
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of your function conditions inside the loop, you are using  **reader.nextDouble()**. This will only read the number (e.g "8") input not the new line (the enter) which is entered by the user after the number. 
Following code for the minus(-) function will not print "Would you like to perform a calculation? (y/n) " twice as the new line is already read. Here **reader.nextLine()** is used instead of **reader.nextDouble()**. **reader.nextLine()** will read the whole line not only the number.

```
if (funct.equals("-"))
        {
            System.out.println("Simple subtraction calculator");
            System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
            fnum = Double.parseDouble( reader.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
            snum = Double.parseDouble( reader.nextLine());
            answer = fnum - snum;
            System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It runs perfectly now. So just for clarification the reader.nextDouble(); was reading the double and letting the enter past causing the println to repeat, and the Double.parseDouble( reader.nextLine()); reads the whole line, only lets the double through and gets rid of the enter? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes @Kieran *reader.nextLine()* reads the while line and *nextDouble()* reading the double.

Answer (score 2):

You need to consume the newline character after you call nextDouble() and before the next nextLine() to prevent nextLine() consume the newline character. Otherwise **funct = reader.nextLine();** will take the new line character as input and not wait for any more user input, which results in the repeat.

```
if (funct.equals("/"))
            {
                System.out.println("Simple division calculator");
                System.out.println("Enter first num: ");
                fnum = reader.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second num: ");
                snum = reader.nextDouble(); // consume the new line character
                reader.nextLine();
                answer = fnum / snum;
                System.out.println("Answer: " + answer);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this reader.nextLine(); before the while loop ends, as mentioned below. This will clear the screen buffer.

`else if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    reader.nextLine();
                }`

Hope this helps,

Comment: Can you please explain about clearing screen buffer? That would help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is when you are using the `reader.nextLine()` method, there is still a newline character left in the buffer, which is picked up when calling nextLine(). So it's making an extra run with the newline character. If you run your program with newline as the input even for the first time, it will loop without doing anything. So, you just need to clear out the buffer before going into your while loop.